# List names of sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I found code to list the names of all the sheets in Google Sheets

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  for (var i=2 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

But we must place =sheetnames() in a cell to get value.
Is there any improvement in the script to automatically update when creating a new sheet?

Comment: Focus on one problem only at a time. There is not a trigger to run a function when a new sheet is created. See the list of available triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). I am afraid the solution can only be a workaround.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer, I hope this is helpful to you. If didn't tackle your additional question, since you should focus on a single specific issue, and that additional question (totally unrelated to the first one) should be asked in another post. Please be aware that posts containing multiple, unrelated questions are likely to get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install an [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) trigger, which runs a function whenever a user modifies the structure of the spreadsheet—for example, when a sheet is inserted or removed.

You can install the trigger manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, executing this function once:

```
function createOnChangeTrigger() {  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("writeSheetNames")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}
```

Once this is installed, the function `writeSheetNames` will run every time a sheet is created, removed, or renamed. This function should do two things:

- Retrieve the sheet names of all the sheets in the spreadsheet.
- Write these sheet names to the cell you indicate.

For example, the function below would write the data to column `A` of the sheet named `Sheet1`.

#### Code sample:

```
function writeSheetNames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => [sheet.getName()]);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("A:A").clear(); // Delete previous data
  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheetNames.length).setValues(sheetNames);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange())

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked with me.

Comment: @lamblichus Oh, I just ticked 'accept this answer' for your answer. It solved my problem very well.
I have another question as link below. Could you please have a look at your convenience?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/64907343/14660513

Cheers,

Comment: @DucNguyen Hi! I saw someone already posted an answer to your new question, I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: @lamblichus, I have fixed that. Thanks a lot.