# Script to get link to the cell automatically

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a template sheet and looking for a script to get link of the active sheet to a specific cell (the same result when right-clicking on cell -> 'Get link to this cell' -> Paste.
[Get link to this cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5prRM.png)

It means when I do a copy from the template sheet, the newly created sheet will automatically get the link for it.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done fairly easy!

```
function getLink() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  let link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+spreadsheet.getId()+"/edit#gid="+sheet.getIndex()+"&range=A1"
  return link;
}
```

The range chosen here was `A1`, but depending on the exact requirements, you can also pass the range parameter to the `link` variable programmatically.

In order to build the link, the `getId()` and the `getIndex()` methods were used in order to retrieve the id of the spreadsheet and the index of the sheet respectively.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getindex);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid).

Comment: Hi @ale13, I tried to do it with your script, but it didn't work with me. It didn't return the link in active sheet. Could you please help to have a look?
Sorry I'm a newbie in this field. Much appreciated.

Comment: What are you getting in return? Are you getting any errors? The script above returns for me the link referring to `A1` cell from the active sheet from the active spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you do a `Logger.log(link)` before the `return` - what are you receiving? @DucNguyen

Comment: Thanks @ale13 so much. I got it.