# Creating a list from tab names but looking to exclude specific tabs (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking to list all tab names in a workbook which I followed a response by user Iamblichus and it works great. Only thing I would like to exclude 4 specific tabs in the workbook. The scripts are as follows:

```
function createOnChangeTrigger() {  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("writeSheetNames")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}



function writeSheetNames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => [sheet.getName()]);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet24");
  sheet.getRange("A:A").clear(); // Delete previous data
  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheetNames.length).setValues(sheetNames);
}
```

First create a trigger then the execution. Would like to exclude 4 specific tabs. Thank you.

Original help found here:
[List names of sheets in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889781/list-names-of-sheets-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function writeSheetNames() {
  const excl = ['Sheet1'];//sheet names to exclude
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => [sheet.getName()]).filter(n => !~excl.indexOf(n[0]));
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet24");
  sheet.getRange("A:A").clear(); // Delete previous data
  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheetNames.length).setValues(sheetNames);
}
```

Comment: So this does work but it removes the formatting in the a column every time, the previous function did not do this. Any further help is gladly appreciated!

Comment: Well this is the part that provides the functional to exclude sheet names: `const sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => [sheet.getName()]).filter(n => !~excl.indexOf(n[0]));` so just incorporate that into the old function and you're done.